# Difference between getCarrierName and getDisplayName in SubscriptionInfo on Android

Tags: android

I have been trying to figure out what is the difference between `getCarrierName` and `getDisplayName` in the Subscription info class. The description from Android documentation doesn't help a lot.

[getDisplayName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo.html#getDisplayName()) - the name displayed to the user that identifies this subscription

[getCarrierName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo.html#getCarrierName())
- the name displayed to the user that identifies Subscription provider name

I think one of them is for the home network and the other is for current network (home or roaming). But I wasn't able to distinguish which one is which. My guess is `getCarrierName` returns home network and `getDisplayName` returns current network but I am honestly not sure.

Comment: once i disabled a sim card, and then the display or carrier name, i don't remember which, started showing "emergency calls only" instead

Comment: @nandsito carrier name seems to show this information. But I am more interested in the behavior it has in roaming network. Because if it shows what you hinted, it has very little use to me :(